# concatenate dynamic columns using google appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to concatenate columns that are dynamic, using appscript programmatically.

See the screenshot what my data looks like and what output i am trying to achieve:

[image]

I was able to achieve concatenation of static/fixed no. of columns using the below code.

```
function concatenate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheetName.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheetName.getLastColumn();
  var rangeValue = sheetName.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, lc).getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<rangeValue.length; i++) {
      var setRange = sheetName.getRange(i+2, lc);
      setRange.setValue(rangeValue[i][0] + " " + rangeValue[i][1] + " " + rangeValue[i][2])
  };
};
```

All i want to achieve now is, the same above for DYNAMIC columns. I tried my best to figure it out, but in vain. Any help would be much greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors when attempting to run this?

Comment: @PhillipThomas The above code doesnt throw any error, and it outputs just like the column D in my screenshot. The situation is that, the data column is  dynamic and may have more columns , and how do i handle it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Splicing in another column**

This assumes that you start with only your data columns and that you have not added the header for the new column. It can be made to work both ways but you just need to know what your starting with.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
      vA[i].splice(vA[i].length,0,'Concatenate');
    }else{
      vA[i].splice(vA[i].length,0,vA[i].join(' '));
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks cooper for your timely response. I tested, but it threw the following error:
TypeError: Cannot find function join in object how are you how are you.

Comment: Try it again.  I left the `[i]` out of the first `vA` in each line of the if statement

Comment: Yeh.  I tested it.  It works now.  Sorry about that.

Comment: ahh! Awesome! Didnt know splicing could be used to this extent(for concatenation). Cant thank you enough, as i was breaking my head trying to find a workaround programmatically. much appreciated @cooper!

Comment: I didn't either until I started hanging around this website a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by just looping through the columns using the last column index `lc` variable you already have. Should look something like this:

```
function concatenate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheetName.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheetName.getLastColumn();
  var rangeValue = sheetName.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, lc).getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < rangeValue.length; i++) {
    var catValues = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < lc; j++) {
      catValues += rangeValue[i][j] + " ";
    }
    var setRange = sheetName.getRange(i+2, lc);
    setRange.setValue(catValues);
  };
};
```

Or if you wanted to get fancy with `.join()`:

```
function concatenate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheetName.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheetName.getLastColumn();
  var rangeValue = sheetName.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, lc).getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < rangeValue.length; i++) {
    var catValues = sheetName.getRange(i, lc).getValues().join(" ");
    var setRange = sheetName.getRange(i+2, lc);
    setRange.setValue(catValues);
  };
};
```

Comment: @Philip Thomas
The looping through columns using column index **lc** worked fine. However the **.join()** threw the following error: 
TypeError: Cannot find function join in object Range.

Comment: @Bala Whoops, that should be fixed by adding the `.getValues()`

Comment: @Bala Glad it worked out. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Philip i already did, but since i do not have enough reputation, it isnt shown as recorded publicly.