# Concatenate Dynamic Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, concatenation

I grabbed some code from here and it's almost perfect but I need to adjust it and I have fiddled around with it a lot but haven't managed to get it right.

I have the following data:

| Student ID | First Name | Last Name | Period | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | John | Doe | A2 | 10/28/2021 | 10/29/2021 |
| 2222222 | Jane | Doe | A2 | 10/28/2021 |  |

With the code that I got from here, it concatenates the dates from all of the date columns and places them into the last column of the spreadsheet with a space between them, which is almost what I need.  I need it to place the concatenated dates into the last column of the spreadsheet, but with a comma and space between them.
Ex:
Right now, based on the table above it would look like this: 10/28/2021 10/29/2021 for John Doe's row.  I want it to look like this: 10/28/2021, 10/29/2021

Can anyone help tweak this code to achieve that?

```
  function message() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = sheetName.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheetName.getLastColumn();
  var rangeValue = sheetName.getRange(2, 5, lr-1, lc).getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < rangeValue.length; i++) {
    var catValues = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < lc; j++) {
      catValues += rangeValue[i][j] + " ";
    }
    var setRange = sheetName.getRange(i+2, lc);
    setRange.setValue(catValues);
    
  };
};
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: where did you get the code from? "here" shows nothing. Then again give a better sample, maybe you can solve your problem with formulas and don't have to go to google-scripts

Comment: I got it from this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648669/concatenate-dynamic-columns-using-google-appscript)

Comment: Did you try a column with join(", ", rangeWithDates) ? Do you HAVE to go to script?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function mymap() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;//starting row of data
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  rg.clearContent();
  let vo = vs.map((r => {
    let arr = r.slice();
    arr.splice(arr.length, 0, `${r[4]},${r[5]}`);
    return arr;
  }))
  let lr = sh.getLastRow();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vo.length, vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!  Worked perfectly!

Comment: Upon further inspection, this only works for two records.  I am tracking tutorial attendance for a full nine week period that consists of 40 days.  I need it to concatenate all the dates that are present for a particular student, not just the first two times they attended a tutorial.  Would you be willing to help me with this adjustment to your code?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of rows except for sheet.getLastRow() -1 which it has to be if the starting row is 2.  I add the sr variable which represents the starting row of the data and I modified the getRange() parameters.  But I can see no reason why it would limit you to two rows.  Please provide me with a table of data that I can copy and paste and I'll show you the results.